# Norton bundled with Shockwave installation has no “No” option. How do i get rid of it?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Norton was bundled with Shockwave when I installed it. There was no option not to install it anywhere in the installation process.

How do I get rid of it? It doesn’t have a separate entry in *Add/Remove Programs*, nor does it have an uninstallation file in the *Program Files* folder. (I haven’t rebooted yet, so I do not know if this matters.)

I do not want Norton on my computer as I’m fairly certain it will mess with my other antivirus.

Answer (score 2):

Reboot, then see if it shows up and you can uninstall normally. If not, run it once to identify what exactly has been installed, then use the appropriate **Norton Removal Tool** from [here](https://www-secure.symantec.com/norton-support/jsp/help-solutions.jsp?docid=kb20080710133834EN_EndUserProfile_en_us&lg=en&ct=us&product=home&version=current&pvid=f-home) or [here](https://www-secure.symantec.com/norton-support/jsp/help-solutions.jsp?docid=20080710133834EN&product=home&pvid=f-home&version=1&lg=en&ct=us).